# Не могу разобраться с getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, minecraft, forge

Приветсвую всех. Хочу получить информацию из файла.
Файл находится по пути `java\ru\nitdroid\herobrine\common\buildings\traps\1.dat`

Пытаюсь вытащить его при помощи кода:

`InputStream loca = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/buildings/traps/" + file);`

Но по итогу получаю Null.

Как мне получить доступ к содержимому этого файла?
Вызываю getResourceAsStream из класса HerobrineBuilder

Структура примерно такая:
[image: структура проекта]

Comment: а почему вы пишете `/resources/` хотя он не в resources? Может правильнее положить в каталог с ресурсами, а не в исходный код

Answer (score 0):

`this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/buildings/traps/" + file);`